# What is the grammar point that we changed the structure "S + V and V" into the structure "S + V, Ving"?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

When reading a story, I often see sentences like this

"**The ogre smiled, showing his rotten teeth**"

I think the original sentence should be "**The ogre smiled and showed his rotten teeth**" or "**The ogre smiled while showing his rotten teeth**"which is reduced into "**The ogre smiled, showing his rotten teeth**".

I also notice they often use this kind of structure with verbs with direct speech.

For example, "**He said 'I don't know', scratching his head**"

Comment: Either ***showing*** or ***which showed*** can be used to indicate that the second statement is in some way ***closely connected*** to the first statement. Connecting the two statements with ***and*** tends to weaken that connection - which is even weaker if the two statements are presented as separate sentences *(The ogre smiled. He showed his rotten teeth)*. Because of the real-world meanings of these two *specific* statements, the connection is obvious anyway, but with different texts, these stylistic choices could affect how the utterances are interpreted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentences like "The ogre smiled, showing his rotten teeth" are good English.  The part "showing his rotten teeth" is a participle clause, which acts adverbially in that it tells us how he smiled, or what the result of his smile was.  It is a "supplemental adjunct" in CEGL-speak, loosely attached to the main clause and providing some additional context.

This can also be used to indicate an action that occurs at the same time as the main action, and is linked to the main action in some way.  The man scratches his head as he speaks, as a gesture to indicate that he is thinking about a problem to which he doesn't know the answer.

Rephrasing with "and" is usually possible. The example with the ogre works fine in both phrasings.  Phrasing with "and" can suggest a sequence of actions.  "He said, I don't know", and scratched his head." suggests he might have scratched his head after speaking. The participle form is better in that example.

Comment: Do you have a source mentioning this?

Comment: This is what CEGL would call supplementary adjunct.  BillJ has written about these over on https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/306036/participle-attachment

Comment: Do you have a proper source written by experts, like ones from Grammarly or Cambridge or the like?

Comment: @Tom: Would you consider chatGPT a "proper" source? What it says looks solid to me.

Comment: Howe about https://nagelhout.faculty.unlv.edu/AGiC/s5i.html  It uses slightly different terminology - but you should be familiar with the fact that if you put three grammarians in a room you will get seven inconsistent sets of terminology...

Comment: Did you forgot "time" in your sentence "at the same ???? as the main action"?

Comment: yes, I did, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I asked chatGPT *What is the difference between "The ogre smiled, showing his rotten teeth" and "The ogre smiled, and showed his rotten teeth"* and got this...

---

The difference between "The ogre smiled, showing his rotten teeth" and "The ogre smiled, and showed his rotten teeth" is the way the action of showing the teeth is described.

In the first sentence, "showing his rotten teeth" is a participial phrase that describes the way the ogre smiled. This construction implies that the act of showing the teeth was a natural part of the smiling, and the two actions occurred simultaneously.

In the second sentence, "and showed his rotten teeth" is a coordinating conjunction that joins two independent clauses. This construction implies that the act of showing the teeth was a separate action that followed the smiling.

Comment: If the OP wanted an AI answer he can ask for it himself.  There is a general policy of "No AI answers", even if they are coincidentally correct.

Comment: As someone called "fumblefingers" said,  "ChatGPT isn't just something to be "minimized" - it has no place here!"  https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5838/is-it-on-topic-to-ask-about-english-advice-given-by-chatgpt

Comment: I'm kinda posting to prove the point. I think it's as good an answer as any likely to be posted by users, and it's just one of an infinitive variety of rephrasings if anyone isn't sure what it's saying. Of course, we've no way of knowing how many answers here are or will be unattributed Cut&Paste from chatGPT and the like. I don't know why I can't mark this as Community Wiki, but if it gets a vote hammering I'm sure my rep can stand it

Comment: https://sapling.ai/ai-content-detector/a7589f881e0735d4767fa05eb1c43598  (available until Sunday)

Comment: This will get interesting. Even if we trust openAI not to deliberately tweak chatGPT to defeat ai-content-detectors (which they could easily do with generative adversarial training), it stands to reason many "bad actors" will be doing this already.

Comment: This is what I got from Chatgpt and it is a bit different from yours "The first sentence, "The ogre smiled, showing his rotten teeth" implies that the ogre smiled in a way that exposed his rotten teeth. The second sentence, "The ogre smiled, and showed his rotten teeth" suggests that the ogre intentionally showed his rotten teeth after smiling. The addition of "and" in the second sentence makes the action of showing the teeth more deliberate."

Comment: I asked ChatGPT "Is it correct to say "My tire has a flat"?"
And it answered

"Yes, it is correct to say "My tire has a flat." This means that the tire is no longer inflated with air and has lost its shape."

I remembered someone telling me that was wrong because "a flat" means "a flat tire". So you can not say "A tire has a flat tire"

Comment: I've flagged this for deletion.  I've no idea what point FF is making here.  But answers that are AI generated  are not needed and should be removed by moderators when they are recognised as such.

Comment: @JamesK: I don't understand why you say "are not needed" there. Maybe it's currently true that you have access to a routine that can reliably identify text written by an AI - but that certainly won't be the case for long, and I'm sure I could easily circumvent it by making a very small number of changes myself. And I *still* think chatGPT's answer is at least as good as your Answer or my "comment-as-answer".

Comment: That's not the point, as you know very well. You said yourself that you are "making a point" - okay point made... now delete and move on.

Comment: This answer isn't needed because if Tom wants to know what kind of thing ChatGPT will say he can use it himself.  In that sense this answer isn't needed.  This also doesn't address the central question of correctness of the participle construction.  AI answers simply don't have a place here.  If they are recognised then they should be deleted. The fact that "others are doing it too" is completely irrelevant. The fact that you might be able to circumvent it is also irrelelevant

Comment: @JamesK: Since Tom is *asking* here, it's unlikely he can tell whether whatever chatGPT tells him is actually true (and there's no doubt it *can* make mistakes). Fortunately for Tom, ***I*** know English well enough to "curate" chatGPT's offering. It obviously didn't give a very good response when Tom asked about *my tire has a flat* (*very* unusual compared to *...has a **puncture***), so if he hadn't already known about that, it wouldn't have been a good idea to rely on chatGPT without a competent native speaker on hand to double-check the response.

Comment: all irrelevant. This is **still** an answer written by an AI, and so should be deleted.  Tom posted here **because** he want an answer written by a human.  Its not about you it is about this posting.  It doesn't matter if it has been "curated" or not.  If you are a competent native speaker (and your previous contributions suggest that you are)  why are you choosing to make a point here?  Especially as you said earlier that "ChatGPT has no place here."  What has changed?  If you are just making a point - fine - point made.

Comment: @JamesK: You don't seem to be meaningfully engaging with what I'm saying, so clearly I haven't even "made my point" with ***you***, let alone with any other users who might want to think this through. It's true that [**ELU** mods have unilaterally banned AI-generated answers](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15500/announcement-ai-generated-answers-are-officially-banned-here), but I'm not aware that **ELL** has taken any such line...

Comment: ... and despite anything I said on the ELL Meta question [Is it on topic to **ask abou**t English advice given by ChatGPT?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5838/), I happen to think chatGPT is potentially an invaluable resource for *learners*. Especially when used with care, which I think I have done here.

Comment: You are right! So I asked on Meta: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5878/are-answers-written-by-ais-suitable-for-the-site/5879#5879

Comment: Thank you. It'll be interesting to see how this plays out. As I recall, my primary concern when commenting on the earlier ELL Meta post was that chatGPT would operate against the interests of *the site itself* - even if it was actually in the best interests of *querents* that both they and high-rep users like ourselves should leverage chatGPT in a range of contexts. Imho things here aren't the same as ELU in general, but *specifically*, I see a big difference between me posting chatGPT's "Answer" ("verified" by me) and a querent asking whether something chatGPT said was true and/or idiomatic.